# How to avoid creating different callbacks in react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The offical documentation of react states:

`<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>`

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

Now let's say I am using a functional component:

```
function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {counter}
        <br />
            <button onClick={() => setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 3)}>CLICKME</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here I also have a new callback every time. And I cannot lift it outside due to the state hook.
Can we somehow emulate the behavior of class component?

```
type State = {
    counter: number,
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    state: State = {
        counter: 0,
    };

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter + 33
        }))
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.counter}
                <br/>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICKME</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of the confusion with function components is that they follow a different development philosophy. While class components try to limit renders using `shouldComponentUpdate` that uses a referential comparison, which creating a new function each render for something like on click would definitely upset, function components are more about quick renders and targeted memoization. Function components do not do the same `shouldComponentUpdate` check that class components do (unless you wrap them in `React.memo()`) and rerender when their parents do anyway.

Comment: There are times when you will want to pass a consistent reference to a function, which other people have already pointed out can be done with `useCallback` or by returning a function from `useMemo`. The reason could be something like swapping between function and class components, using the function as a dependency to a `useEffect`, `useMemo`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the callback in the memory and not creating a new callback every rerender you can use useCallback or useMemo

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)
[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: He is using class components not functional components.

Comment: he didn't mention that "Now let's say I am using a functional component:

" he's using functional components and he wants to emulate the behaviour of class component (methods not callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

You could call the function on user click. This is the functional example to achieve the same `onClick={this.handleClick}`

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCounter(counter + 33);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {counter}
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>CLICKME</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: but isn't `handleClick` recreated here too? Or is `App()` only called once?